# Java JNI NullPointerException after calling method from C with valid pointers

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-native-interface, embedded-linux

TLDR: I'm getting a NPE when I call a Java method from C and nothing obvious is jumping out as the cause.

I have written some JNI code on Linux to call the system call `poll` for me (to get notifications from an attached device).

Most of it is working pretty well; my C methods are getting called, I'm getting a string from Java, returning a pointer (as an `int`... I know, so sue me!), and successfully passing that to other methods. I've got a lot of `printf`s to verify this.

The problem is happening in my C method `Java_NativePoller_poll` below. The line that does `CallVoidMethod` *seems* to work, as the `printf` which follows *is* called, but the Java method I'm attempting to call never gets called, and a `NullPointerException` is then thrown.

Here's the Java code:

```java
public class NativePoller {
    public interface NativePollEventHandler {
        void handleEvent();
    }

    /* Opens a file to prepare to poll its status */
    public native int watchFile(String fileName, NativePollEventHandler handler);

    /* Poll a file previously opened */
    public synchronized native void poll(int fd);

    /* Clean up */
    public native void stopWatching(int fd);
}
```

And the C code in question:

```c
struct Poller {
        struct pollfd fd;
        jobject handler;
        jclass objclass;
        jmethodID method;
};

int wasEx(JNIEnv* env) {
        jthrowable ex = (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env);
        if (ex) {
                printf("Got an exception!");
                (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
                (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativePoller_watchFile
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject nativePoller, jstring fileName, jobject handler) {
        (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
        const char* file = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, fileName, NULL);
        if (wasEx(env)) return -1;
        int fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading (errno=%d)\n", file, errno);
                (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, fileName, file);
                if (wasEx(env)) return -1;
                return fd;
        }

        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, fileName, file);
        if (wasEx(env)) return -1;

        struct Poller* poller = malloc(sizeof(struct Poller));
        poller->fd.fd = fd;
        poller->fd.events = POLLIN;
        poller->handler = handler;
        jclass objclass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, handler);
        if (wasEx(env)) return -1;
        jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, objclass, "handleEvent", "()V");
        if (wasEx(env)) return -1;

        printf("Found method %p in class %p\n", method, objclass);

        poller->objclass = objclass;
        poller->method = method;

        printf("Returning poller %p which has descriptor %d\n", poller, poller->fd.fd);

        return (int)poller;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativePoller_poll
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject nativePoller, jint pollerAddress) {
        struct Poller* poller = (struct Poller*)pollerAddress;
        printf("Polling for %p (%d)\n", poller, poller->fd.fd);
        int ret = poll(&poller->fd, 1, 1);
        if (ret > 0) {
                printf("Got something! Events is %08X", poller->fd.events);
                if (poller->fd.events & POLLIN) {
                        if (poller->method != 0) {
                                printf("Calling: CallVoidMethod(%p, %p, %p)...\n", env, poller->handler, poller->method);
                                (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
                                (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, poller->handler, poller->method);
                                if (wasEx(env)) return;
                                printf("Called.\n");
                        }
                }
        }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativePoller_stopWatching
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject nativePoller, jint fileDescriptor) {
        struct Poller* poller = (struct Poller*)fileDescriptor;
        close(poller->fd.fd);
        free(poller);
}
```

(Sorry the code isn't super clean -- I still have a bit of refactoring to do.)

Here's the code that's calling it:

```java
watchFd = nativePoller.watchFile(ROOT_PATH + pinPath + "value", this::triggerEvent);

//...

private void triggerEvent() {
    LOG.info("Event triggered!");
}
```

All my `printf` output looks like this:

```
Found method 0x63d03b48 in class 0x63d02860
Returning poller 0x63d036a8 which has descriptor 18
Polling for 0x63d036a8 (18)
Got something! Events is 00000001
Calling: CallVoidMethod(0x63d03d3c, 0x630d0aa8, 0x63d03b48)...
Got an exception!
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at my.package.NativePoller.poll(Native Method)
        at my.package.GPIOPinImpl.run(GPIOPinImpl.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Where's this NPE coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: _"The line that does CallVoidMethod seems to work, as the printf which follows is called"_. The exception will be pending until control returns back to Java, which is why you didn't see the NPE until your native method returned. You have very little error checking in your code. You really ought to verify that every JNI call that isn't supposed to return NULL indeed didn't return NULL, and also call `ExceptionCheck` efter each JNI call that could result in an exception being thrown.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I've edited to add exception checking in C around the call in question, so it's now "handled" in C. I'm also printing out the exact arguments I'm calling the function with just before I call it, so you can be assured I'm not passing `NULL` into `CallVoidMethod`.

Comment: Well, the object and method addresses you print in `"Got something!"` and `"Calling: CallVoidMethod"` don't match, so that's something you'll have to look into. You should probably use a `jlong` for the `Poller*` instead of a `jint`, since many computers these days use 64-bit pointers. And I found it a bit strange to have the name `fileDescriptor` for something that is a `Poller*`.

Comment: Thanks again for commenting. I did say in my OP that I've got some refactoring to do. Renaming that variable was part of it.

Comment: I'm writing this for a specific embedded platform and know the architecture so it's always going to be a 32-bit pointer. If I change it to a `jlong` then I get warnings from C that I' casting to a pointer from an integer of a different size on my platform (ARM Cortex-A7, btw).

Comment: I don't really know why it wasn't working, but I ended up refactoring a bit so more of the code is in Java and instead of having the C code call a method in another class, it just calls a method on its own class (`this`) which in turn calls the actual handler. That seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reusing `jobject handler` and `jclass objclass` across method calls. This is illegal unless the references are made global.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913440/jni-environment-pointer-in-a-static-c-object-and-calling-a-java-function-takin/35950745#35950745) for details.

Comment: Ah! That'd be it! Thanks very much.