# Oop gets corrupted when using in another JNI function

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot

The question is can we cache `jclass` and `jmethodID` across different JNI methods invocation?

I faced some strange behavior when trying to create an object of some specific class with cached `jclass` and `jmethodID` from another JNI method invocation.

Here is a simple example:

```
public class Main {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("test-crash");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        doAnotherAction(doSomeAction());
    }

    private static native long doSomeAction();

    private static native void doAnotherAction(long ptr);
}

public class MyClass {
    public int a;

    public MyClass(int a) {
        if(a == 10){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("a == 10");
        }
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

What the JNI functions do is just creating objects of the class `MyClass`. The function `doSomeAction` return a pointer pointing to a cached `jclass` and `jmethodID`. Here is the implementation of native methods:

```
struct test{
    jclass mc;
    jmethodID ctor;
};

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_test_Main_doSomeAction
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass jc){
  (void) jc;

  jclass mc = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/test/MyClass");
  jmethodID ctor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, mc, "<init>", "(I)V");

  struct test *test_ptr = malloc(sizeof *test_ptr);
  test_ptr->mc = mc;
  test_ptr->ctor = ctor;

  printf("Creating element0\n");
  jobject ae1 = (*env)->NewObject(env, test_ptr->mc, test_ptr->ctor, (jint) 0);
  (void) ae1;

  printf("Creating element0\n");
  jobject ae2 = (*env)->NewObject(env, test_ptr->mc, test_ptr->ctor, (jint) 0);
  (void) ae2;

  printf("Creating element0\n");
  jobject ae3 = (*env)->NewObject(env, test_ptr->mc, test_ptr->ctor, (jint) 0);
  (void) ae3;

  return (intptr_t) test_ptr;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_Main_doAnotherAction
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass jc, jlong ptr){
  (void) jc;

  struct test *test_ptr= (struct test *) ptr;
  jclass mc = test_ptr->mc;
  jmethodID ctor = test_ptr->ctor;

  printf("Creating element\n");
  jobject ae1 = (*env)->NewObject(env, mc, ctor, (jint) 0);
  (void) ae1;

  printf("Creating element\n");
  jobject ae2 = (*env)->NewObject(env, mc, ctor, (jint) 0);
  (void) ae2;

  printf("Creating element\n");
  jobject ae3 = (*env)->NewObject(env, mc, ctor, (jint) 0); //CRASH!!
  (void) ae3;
}
```

The problem is the program is crash when dereferencing `0` when trying to create object in the `Java_com_test_Main_doAnotherAction`. Crash occurs at `object_alloc` function calling `java_lang_Class::as_Klass(oopDesc*)`.

Dissasmebly of `java_lang_Class::as_Klass(oopDesc*)` is

```
Dump of assembler code for function _ZN15java_lang_Class8as_KlassEP7oopDesc:                                                                                                                                       
   0x00007f7f6b02eeb0 <+0>:     movsxd rax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x932ab5]        # 0x7f7f6b96196c <_ZN15java_lang_Class13_klass_offsetE>                                                                                 
   0x00007f7f6b02eeb7 <+7>:     push   rbp                                                                                                                                                                         
   0x00007f7f6b02eeb8 <+8>:     mov    rbp,rsp                                                                                                                                                                     
   0x00007f7f6b02eebb <+11>:    pop    rbp                                                                                                                                                                         
   0x00007f7f6b02eebc <+12>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rdi+rax*1]                                                                                                                                                   
   0x00007f7f6b02eec0 <+16>:    ret
```

`rdi` here seems to contain a pointer to the relevant `Oop`. What I noticed is the first 5 times where no crash occurred:

```
rdi            0x7191eb228
```

The crash case is

```
rdi            0x7191eb718
```

Causing `0x0` to be returned and crash.

What does get `Oop` corrupted when using `jclass` and `jmethodID` across different `JNI` functions? If I create objects with a locally found `jclass` and `jmethodID` everything works just fine.

UPD: After analyzing core dump I figured out that the rdi is being loaded as

```
mov    rdi,r13
#...
mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rdi]
```

While the `r13` does not seem to be update inside JNI functions of mine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caching `jclass` across JNI calls is a major ([though typical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35950745/3448419)) mistake.
`jclass` is a [special case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/types.html#reference-types) of `jobject` - it is a JNI reference and should be managed.

As JNI spec [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/design.html#global-and-local-references), *all Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references*.
So, `FindClass` returns a local JNI reference which becomes invalid as soon as the native method returns. That is, GC will not update the reference if the object is moved, or another JNI call may reuse the same slot for a different JNI reference.

In order to cache `jclass` across JNI calls, you may convert it to a global reference using [`NewGlobalRef`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewGlobalRef) function.

`jthread`, `jstring`, `jarray` are other examples of `jobjects`, and they should also be  managed.

`JNIEnv*` must not be cached, too, because it is valid only [in the current thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#attaching-to-the-vm).

At the same time `jmethodID` and `jfieldID` can be safely reused across JNI calls - they unambiguously identify a method/field in the JVM and are [intended for repeated use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/design.html#accessing-fields-and-methods) as long as the holder class is alive. However, they may also become invalid if the holder class happens to be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks. The question is where the documentation if a created object Locally or Globally referenced can be found. I re-read the docs for [FindClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#FindClass) and it is not really clear from it. Are there other objects except `jmethodID` and `jfieldID` that can be safely reused across JNI calls?

Comment: @St.Antario I've updated the answer with the relevant links to the JNI spec.

Comment: @apangin I've heard there are also problems with holding too many (and you can reach this "too many" quite easily) local and global reference. Could you please explain which objects are safe and don't "take up" a space and which should be cached with caution? jclass, jobject, jfieldID, jmethodID. Is there a difference in regards to these limit if I cache local or global reference?

Comment: @MarcinK. This is a different topic, so please ask a separate question to avoid extended discussion in comments. Also, clarify what problems exactly do you mean.

Comment: @apangin
Here is a question that I created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512072/what-can-cause-jni-references-memory-problems-a-few-detailed-questions